# no pytorch_jni in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, pytorch

I am trying to run [`java-demo`](https://github.com/pytorch/java-demo) on Linux and downloaded pytorch lib from [StartLocally page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cu102/libtorch-shared-with-deps-1.6.0.zip

Unfortunately, this archive file doesn't contain `pytorch_jni`

What can be done?

Comment: You may want to try the JavaCPP Presets for PyTorch instead: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/pytorch That comes bundled with all the needed binaries and loads everything automatically.